# Python: Problem with raw_input, turning the value I get into an array

Tags: python, list, raw-input

I'm having issues with `raw_input` again, this time trying to turn the value I get into a list. Here is my code:

```
original = raw_input("Type is your input? ")
original_as_array = list('original')
print original_as_array
for i in range(0,len(original)):
    print i
```

my print `original_as_array` literally prints `['o', 'r', 'i'.... etc]`. If we pretend that my input is `Hello World`, I want `original_as_array` to output: `['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o'... etc]`. I think I'm making a tiny mistake. Can you point me in the right direction:)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes form a string literal.

```
original_as_array = list(original)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
original = raw_input("Type is your input? ")
original_as_array = list(original) # no quotes. If you put quotes, you are turning it into a string.
print original_as_array
for i in original_as_array: # this is shorter way to iterate and print than your method
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are already iterable, so you don't need to convert it to a list, so you can easily go :

```
original = raw_input("Type is your input? ")
# or if you really want a list
original_as_list = list(original) # NOT 'original', that's passing the string original not the value of original
for letter in original:
    print letter
```